# Weird class instance sizing using class members that are arrays of generic types

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

Below is a very simple bit of code that mimics a class structure in some code I have (the form just contains a single button attached to the click event). I am using Delphi XE and XE II and see nasty crashes when destroying objects in my production code that this class is based on. These crashes only occur if I allow the members of the array item in TMyClass to be initialised in the Clear() method.

Unfortunately the crash is not repeatable so far in this sample code, but it does mimic some very weird behaviour with instance sizing that I suspect might be the cause of the problem.

If I place a break point in the TMyClass.Clear function and look at the InstanceSize member of the class reports 1288. Which is odd, as the size of the array member alone is really 12kb. I can change the type being provided from TRecord2 to Integer and I get the same InstanceSize result. If I remove the array entirely from the class I get an Instance size of ~264 bytes, which seems over the top for a class that contains only a single 128 byte record instance. This indicates that the compiler has allocated 1024 bytes to the array storage for the V (of type TT) member in TMyClass.

I am suspicious that the weird instance size is causing bad things to happen when I write 12kb of data into an object that the compiler thinks is 1kb in size.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TRecord = record A : Array[1..128] of byte; end;
  TRecord2 = packed record S : Single; T : TDateTime; end;

  TBase = class(TObject)
    public
      R : TRecord;
  end;

  TBase2<T> = class(TBase)
    public
      type
        TT = packed array [0..31, 0..31] of T;

      var
        V : TT;
        R2 : TRecord;
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TBase2<TRecord2>)
    public
      procedure Clear;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  O : TMyClass;
begin
  O := TMyClass.Create;
  O.Clear;
  O.Free;
end;

{ TMyClass }

procedure TMyClass.Clear;
var
  i, j : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 31 do
    for j := 0 to 31 do
      begin
        V[I, J].S := 0;
        V[I, J].T := 0;
      end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I'm a little lost what the issue is, but maybe this info will help. Most built-in classes that have a Clear method, that Clear method is called automatically when the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug, as is shown by this minimal reproduction:

```
program InstanceSizeBug;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TMyClass<T> = class
    V: array [0..255] of T;
  end;
  TMyClassSingle = class(TMyClass<Single>);

begin
  Writeln(TMyClass<Single>.InstanceSize);
  Writeln(TMyClassSingle.InstanceSize);
  Readln;
end.
```

Output:

```
1032
264
```

Note that the same behaviour can be observed in Delphi 2010, the only other Delphi version i have to hand.

Trace through under the debugger and you find yourself in `_GetMem` with the `Size` parameter equal to `264` so clearly not enough memory is being allocated.

And just in case there is any doubt, this version fails with an AV.

```
program InstanceSizeBug;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TMyClass<T> = class
    V: array [1..256*256] of T;
  end;
  TMyClassSingle = class(TMyClass<Single>);

begin
  TMyClassSingle.Create.V[256*256] := 0;
end.
```

I have submitted this to Quality Central, issue [#100561](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=100561).

As a workaround I suggest you use a dynamic array which you allocate using SetLength in the constructor. I rather imagine that it is the presence of a fixed sized generic array that is making the compiler misbehave.

Comment: I'd report it. With QC reports does it really matter who enters it? Besides, you seem to have the most/more concise code to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for taking a look. By all means create a Quality Central item for it :-) Do you think there is a work around for this issue? Thanks, Raymond.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this line:   TMyClassSingle.Create.V[256*256] := 0;     I've never seen that syntax before!

Comment: It's just a lazy way to create an object and write to a field in one line. And I needed to make the array large enough to defeat memory manager sub allocation strategy. Naturally it leaks, but since the object isn't even the right size, I plead not guilty your honour!

Comment: I'm good with the creation and field access in one line etc, it's the assignment of a single value to the array in that fashion that's new!

Comment: I'll submit a QC report for the bug later this evening. I don't have an obvious work around for you though.

Comment: Right, I have now submitted the bug to QC.

Comment: Thanks for the dynamic array suggestion - I will give it a go.

Comment: I have modified the code so that it uses a dynamic version of the static array as suggested above. The code no longer crashes with the exception I was experiencing earlier. :-)